# get only hour from datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

how to extract only hour from date and time and convert it to integer so that I can compare to integer??

e.g.

datetime = 2013-02-01 10:24:36.000 i.e in the date and time data type

then

hour = take hour only i.e. 10

then

hour for comparision = Convert.ToInt32(time);

**I have try this to item.StartTime which is date and time:**

```
var time = String.Format("{HH}", (DateTime)item.StartTime);
var hour = Convert.ToInt32(time);
```

**Error:**

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect some variables. You can use (Quick)Watch to see what properties a given object (say a DateTime) has. As for the error you got, inspect the variable 'time' to see why Convert seems to think its format is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just looking for [`DateTime.Hour`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx):

```
int hour = item.StartTime.Hour;
```

... but it has a value of 10, not 24. (`item.StartTime.Minute` would give you 24.)

As a rule of thumb, avoid string conversions unless they're an *inherent* part of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ya sorry I have misplace it with 24 it should be 10

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
int hour = dt.Hour;
```

Its worth getting used to looking these things up in the MSDN documentation. It is pretty good once you get used to it. For a list of `DateTime` members I just google System.DateTime and follow the top MSDN link (which is usually the first link).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to compare this with another date you might be able to save yourself a headache and just use `DateTime.Compare`.

```
public static int Compare(
    DateTime t1,
    DateTime t2
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

Answer (score -1):

//In Single line

int Time = DateTime.Now.Hour;